# Set Enviroment Variable that contains two paths interelated paths

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to create a custom environment variable that uses python to execute a py file.

Here is an example of what I have

```
export VAR=${VAR}:"/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/user/file"
```

When I use the variable I get the output:

bash: :/usr/bin/python2.7: No such file or directory

If I echo the variable I get the output:

/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/user/file

EDIT:

Trying "$VAR" gives me the output

bash: :/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/user/file: No such file or directory

If I run just this /usr/bin/python2.7 /home/user/file it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think an alias is more appropriate for all kinds like this (you may consider a more suitable name for the alias)

```
alias var="/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/user/file"
```

If you want to stick with your version you have to tell your shell to evaluate the content of `VAR`.

For this you just have to invoke

```
eval ${VAR}
```

By the way, why do you append the string `"/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/user/file"` to `VAR` instead of overwriting the content of `VAR`?

Comment: This works. However now when I open up the terminal it will say bash: alias: /home/user/file: not found.

Comment: sorry, i forget the quotes! Just out of curiosity: why don't you put `#!/usr/bin/python2.7` in the first line of `/home/usr/file` and make `/usr/usr/file` executable with `chmod +x /home/usr/file`